# Running multiple Hive / map reduce jobs - Killing TempletonController jobs

Tags: apache-spark, hive, mapreduce

I checked my cluster status and I noticed that there were 60 pending or in progress map/reduce jobs in yarn. I killed all TempletonController jobs in yarn and all pending jobs finished successfully quickly. I know that TempletonController is a parent process to execute the inner Map/Reduce jobs, so why didn't killing them didn't make the other jobs fail?

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS crnw_db;
USE crnw_db;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crnw (
Time TIMESTAMP,
Sensorvalue DOUBLE
)
PARTITIONED BY (year STRING, month STRING, day STRING, customer STRING, site STRING, machine STRING, sensorname STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/data/storage/';
MSCK REPAIR TABLE crnw;
```

Comment: Why is it tagged [apache-spark]?

Comment: The data pipeline is a combination of Spark jobs and Hive jobs.